# putting two dictionaries into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to put two dictionaries into a single (new) dictionary but I keep having problems. I get this error message:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

which doesn't make sense because I defined r1 and r2 in my function:

```
def combine_report(r1, r2):
    to_merge=[r1,r2]
    d={}
    for m in to_merge:
        for k,v in m.items():
            d.setdefault(k,{}).update(v)
    return d
```

Comment: And what are the dictionaries you use as input for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.update()` directly on `d`:

```
def combine_report(r1, r2):
    d = r1.copy()
    d.update(r2)
    return d
```

You were trying to set keys to empty dictionaries, then calling `.update()` on those with just the value; this requires that that value is *iterable*; if one ofyour values is `None` that'd lead to your specific exception:

```
>>> {}.update(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Your version could be 'repaired' by using simple item assignment:

```
def combine_report(r1, r2):
    to_merge = [r1, r2]
    d={}
    for m in to_merge:
        for k, v in m.items():
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

but using `.update()` like shown in my version is going to be more efficient.

If you have to have all values preserved in a list per key, then use:

```
def combine_report(r1, r2):
    d = {}
    for m in to_merge:
        for k, v in m.items():
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return d
```

Here, [`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) will return the value for key `k`, but if `k` is not yet present sets a default value (here a list).

Comment: Will `update` be more efficient than dictionary comprehension?

Comment: @thefourtheye: I'd expect so, yes. The C code can reuse the existing dictionary structure, and a loop in C beats a loop in Python any time.

Comment: You mean, comprehensions are implemented in Python, not in C?

Comment: @thefourtheye: yes, the `for` loop is still compiled to byte code.

Comment: Cool :) BTW, his requirement has changed a little, please check his first comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    d.setdefault(k,{}).update(v)
```

You should go with

```
    d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
```

Because, you are trying to update dictionaries with just values. What you actually need is the list of values corresponding to the keys. So, the whole program becomes like this

```
def combine_report(r1, r2):
    to_merge, d = [r1,r2], {}
    for m in to_merge:
        for k,v in m.items():
            d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
    return d

print(combine_report({"1":"a"}, {"1":"b"}))
```

**Output**

```
{'1': ['a', 'b']}
```

Comment: does this combine them even if they have the same values for one key? I don't want any values to be replaced. if I have one report as {'1':'a'} and another as {'1':'b'} I want to get {'1': 'a', 'b'}

Comment: @user2976821 Please check my updated answer. It will behave as you expected.

Comment: @user2976821: that is not a valid Python dictionary. You'll then have to use a list for all values, always.

Comment: @user2976821 If the key is not found in the dictionary, it will create the key and the value corresponding to that will be the second parameter we pass to `setdefault`. In this case, we create new keys and the values are empty lists.